# New lines for a text inside a div when reducing the width

Tags: css

I have this code below. As you can see the `width` of the div container is 40%. When I reduce the width, the green `div` goes down keeping `foobar's` in the same line. I expected the words (`foobar2`, `foobar3`) go down below `foobar1` instead. Why this behaviour?

This is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HRHRT/).

```
<div style="width: 40%; background-color: blue">
  <div style="display: inline-block; background-color: red">hello</div>
  <div style="display: inline-block; background-color: green">foobar1 foobar2 foobar3 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's because foobar1 - 3 are in the same div.

Comment: but look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/E8Lnn/ The words are also in the same div, but they are in different lines when the width is reduced.

Comment: Because the width is fixed to 80 px. Check this update to the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/E8Lnn/1/ And see what happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the use of inline-block. For this purpose you might be better using a `<span>` element (the equivalent of setting it to `display: inline`).

```
<div style="width: 40%; background-color: blue">
  <span style="background-color: red">hello</div>
  <span style="background-color: green">foobar1 foobar2 foobar3 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using style="display: inline-block; This displays the div in the same line.

Answer (score 0):

It's because foobar1, foobar2, foobar3 are inside the same div. So they will be on the same line. If you do something like this, you'll get the desired results.

```
<div style="width: 40%; background-color: blue">
  <div style="display: inline-block; background-color: red">hello</div>
  <div style="display: inline-block; background-color: green">foobar1</div>
  <div style="display: inline-block; background-color: green">foobar2</div>
  <div style="display: inline-block; background-color: green">foobar3 </div>
</div>
```

**PS**. There are better ways to do this. I am just modifying your question to help you understand better.

A fiddle to demonstrate this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/5uPPT/)